# How to change the application language when button will tapped in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, localization

How to change the application whole language, When application will launch it select the language button will tapped the total application language will be change.

Comment: You need in app localisation this might help https://github.com/marmelroy/Localize-Swift

Comment: welcome !! , Click here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51018827/4601900 for sample code

Comment: This is duplicate, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416923/ios-how-to-change-app-language-programmatically-without-restarting-the-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a plist file for each language you're targeting. When a certain button is clicked on, you just change the target plist file accordingly.

For example, let's say you have two languages available for your app.
when a user selects English for the default language, the plist file from which all string come is set to the English one.