# Swift: iOS multiple language set label text from storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

My application have 3 language

For text in code, I can use `Localizable.string` file for set text for languages.

But for `labels` in `storyboard` I cant set `Localizable.string` value

How I can?

[image]

Comment: You can do it by code, calling yourself `NSLocalizedString()`.

Comment: @Larme by this way, i most create IBOutlet for all my texts! my texts is very lot

Comment: What's the point of having Localizable.string if you don't utilize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an extension of the `UIKit` component and `localized` text inside the `awakeFromNib`

Here is demo

```
extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: /** Your Bundle */, value: "", comment: "")
    }
}
```

For `UILabel`

```
extension UILabel {
    open override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        if let textValue = self.text {
            self.text = textValue.localized
        }
    }
}
```

For `UIButton`

```
extension UIButton {
    open override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        if let text = self.title(for: self.state) {
            self.setTitle(text.localized, for: self.state)
        }
    }
}
```

For `UITextField`

```
extension UITextField {
    open override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        if let placeHolderValue = self.placeholder {
            self.placeholder = placeHolderValue.localized
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a need to safe unwrap (if let) since `self.text`/`self.placeholder` can be nil, no? Also, I'd also try the `text` of the `UITextField`, just in case that somewhere there is a pre-defined value. And for the button, you might want to iterate over each state too, no?

Comment: @Larme. Yes, no need to unwrap for label and placeholder. Also, I do not agree with you for adding text as localized for text field text. It will create a problem when a user enters the same value. For the button no need to iterate over each state.

Comment: When the user enters the same value? It's fine, your method is called on awake from nib only. Also, you are covering your use cases,, but in fact you could have different text for different states in the button, in ONE textField only, a pre-set value for text, and no placeholder...

Comment: @Larme Thanx I got your point. I will update

Answer (score 1):

Xcode supports localisation of storyboard, which is described [in this iOS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html%22)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51018827/1971013) may also be helpful.

There are various tools and methods to localise.  I'd advise you to take some time to read about.  As it's an old and important subject, there's a ton of information.

Comment: I saw this article, but I cant use it. not work for me

Comment: @Mohammad Why can't use this?