# Swift: load string text of Main.strings from Locazilable.string

Tags: swift, xcode

I have `Locazilable.string` and into this file I have 3 languages

I want load text from `Locazilable.string` and put in Main.string

My Locazilable.string:

```
"1" = "aaa";
```

Sample:

```
"4O3-WU-Cfv.text" = "bbb";
```

To:

```
"4O3-WU-Cfv.text" = getFromLocazilable("1"); ????
```

Comment: You can't, `Main.string` which the localization of a Storyboard is only a text file, you can't have "code" inside it. You need to put yourself `"aaa"`.

Comment: @Larme ok thanks. can I set label text in storyboard load from locazilable? I dont want use main.string or NSLocalizedString for static texts

Comment: Yes, see you previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68088940/swift-ios-multiple-language-set-label-text-from-storyboard You can also use a script that can read your `Localizable.string` and replace the values on `Main.string`.

Comment: @Larme i read previous question. but i cant use it. can you help me more with example? thank you

Comment: You could use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/68089060/1801544 ? Why? What went wrong?

Comment: @Larme i want set label text of storyboard from Localizable. but this tutorial use codes and dont understand it

Comment: Add the code from `extension UILabel` inside your app somewhere. Can be its own file. And it should work. In the storyboard, put "1" (the Localizable.strings) key as the text value fo the Label and it should work. If you don't understand answers, comment them and ask authors for more explaination. But you already had the solution...

Comment: @Larme sorry, this work only for one language. i set UserDefaults.standard.set("en", forKey: "AppleLanguages"). I have too change it to UserDefaults.standard.set("English", forKey: "AppleLanguages") ?